# Github pages 404 not found with seems correct settings, what's the problem?

Tags: github-pages

I'm publishing a folder of html files to my github.io pages site. But I got the 404 error:

```
404: NOT_FOUND Code: NOT_FOUND ID: hkg1::8rz8w-1699491784992-0023b3221360
```

Here is the [link to my project](https://github.com/neozhaoliang/test-jbook), it's just a fork of another project, which has a working gh-pages site. And I forked it without any changes to it, just chose the gh-pages branch to deploy the site in my settings page, and settings panel is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Recd.png)

Could anyone tell me what's the problem with my settings?

I checked my domain and website, they are alright. I tweaked with the settings panel. These didn't solve the problem.